# SQL Server trigger insert and update operation not working?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2008. My trigger shown below. And I am inserting the values I didn't get any update in two tables .

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInserta ON AMS_33.dbo.access_event_logs
 AFTER INSERT,UPDATE 
 AS           
        declare @idams bigint;  
        declare @id int; 
        declare @uid nvarchar(20);
        declare @tentry datetime;
        declare @tsn nvarchar(20);
        declare @evtid nvarchar(20);
        declare @audit_action nvarchar(300);

select @idams   = i.id from inserted i;
select @id      =  max(Rownumber) + 1   from   TAV3.dbo.access_event_logs ;  
select @uid    =i.USERID from inserted i;   
select @tentry =i.TIMESTAMPS from inserted i;   
select @tsn   =i.TERMINALSN from inserted i;
select @evtid =i.EVENTID from inserted i;
set    @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert.';
set    @tentry = dateadd(hh,3,@tentry); 


insert into TAV3.dbo.access_event_logs 
(Rownumber,Userid, Timeentry, Eventid, Terminalsn, Notes)
 values(@id,@uid, @tentry, @evtid, @tsn, @audit_action);

update AMS_33.dbo.access_event_logs set Calculated=1 where id= @idams;
```

GO

**Table 1 AMS_33.dbo.access_event_logs**

```
  id    bigint  Unchecked
  USERID    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  DEPARTMENT    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  TIMESTAMPS    datetime    Unchecked
  EVENTID   nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  TERMINALSN    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  ACCESSMETHOD  nvarchar(255)   Unchecked
  REMARKS   nvarchar(255)   Unchecked
  TERMINALIP    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  PHOTO image   Checked
  PHOTOSIZE int Unchecked
  RECLOGDTM datetime    Unchecked
  RECLOGFROMIP  nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
  LOCALTIMESTAMP    datetime    Unchecked
  PhotoPath nvarchar(50)    Checked
  Calculated    int Checked
```

**Table 2 TAV3.dbo.access_event_logs**

```
Rownumber   int Unchecked
Userid  nvarchar(20)    Unchecked
Timeentry   datetime    Unchecked
Eventid nvarchar(20)    Checked
Terminalsn  nvarchar(20)    Unchecked
Calculated  int Checked
Notes   nvarchar(300)   Checked
```

Here no insert or update is performing ?

Comment: 1) you are assuming only one row has been inserted or updated, that could be false.

Comment: If I read your code correct you will create a loop by this?! You have a update on that table where you ha ve a trigger on and your trigger update this table again. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming only one row has been inserted or updated, in statements like 
select @idams   = i.id from inserted i;

That could be false. Those statement would then fail never getting to the insert

Comment: Instead of using the value clause on the insert use a select i.e. 
insert ( fielda, fieldb) select inserted.foo as fielda, inserted.bar as fieldb from inserted